# How to load server side in angularjs version below 2

Tags: angularjs

I am using dynamic meta data binding the facebook debugger does not read that.
so I need to load the page server side using angularjs below  version 2 .

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to 'server-side rendering' then I'm afraid that's not a feature that's available in AngularJS

(Remember, AngularJS is the name for all versions of Angular below 2, and it is fundamentally different in architecture.)

If you need server side rendering for whatever reasons then you'll need to use Angular 2+ or some other framework.

Some links that might be helpful:

https://angular.io/guide/universal

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: Hai ChrisM Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I need to share my web page in social media with rich preview 
Can I know how to that